# Archiving Records: Partitioning, Additional Table, or Status Flag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, data-modeling

I'm working on an application where a lot of records need to be archived. For example, in the case of a `task`, *n* number hours after it's been marked complete, it becomes read-only. The frontend client queries for "Active" tasks or "Archived" tasks, but never both mixed together. I'm wondering what the ideal way of storing the archived task records would be as, over time, they will greatly outnumber the "Active" tasks.

I'm interested mainly in preventing the "Active" task query from coming in contact with a bunch of archived tasks and taking a performance hit.

Is flagging / indexing an `archived: boolean` column enough? I was also thinking of partitioning / moving them into their own `archived_tasks` table for total separation, but I'm not sure that's necessary. Any other ideas?

Extra info: Also filtering based on a foreign key for the current user.

Comment: If you are never going to query them together, it's better to move them onto a separate table. Why would you want to index a binary column?

Comment: I think my understanding of how indexing works is flawed. My thought was that by indexing the `archived` column, a search tree would be created that separates archived and unarchived records. This way, a query looking for any unarchived records could ignore most of the records on the first step. If not indexing, what is the appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

"The cardinality of an index is the number of unique values within it. Your database table may have a billion rows in it, but if it only has 8 unique values among those rows, your cardinality is very low.

A low cardinality index is not a major efficiency gain. Most SQL indexes are binary search trees (B-Trees). Versus a serial scan of every row in a table to find matching constraints, a B-Tree logarithmically reduces the number of comparisons that have to be made. **The gains from executing a search against a B-Tree are very low when the size of the tree is small**.

So putting an index on a Boolean field? Or an enumerated value field? **A cardinality of a very small number of distinct values among a very large number of rows will not yield noticeable efficiency gains**. Save your database indexes for fields with very high cardinality to ensure the gains from scanning a B-Tree are largest versus sequential scans."

-- Joshua Ginsberg, Chief Architect, Red Hat.

More about this topic, `http://www.ovaistariq.net/733/understanding-btree-indexes-and-how-they-impact-performance/#.W2gT1H6YPEY`